# Customize ActiveX button from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've made a piece of code that, when you click a button, copies a sheet, strips it for formatting and then adds a new button with a different macro assigned to it.

My problem is that both of my buttons are grey, and I would like to customize them.

The first button is an Excel control element, and is always present on the original sheet. I've altered the font, font size, underlining and made it bold, by right clicking on it and entering the formatting menu, but I can't find the option to change its background color.

The second button is created through VBA and is an ActiveX button. The code to add it is as follows

```
Sub TilføjKnap()
Dim Plads As Range
Dim Knap As OLEObject
Dim Kode As String

    Sheets("Indleveringsplan (2)").Activate
        Set Plads = ActiveSheet.Range("L7:N17")

        Set Knap = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)

        With Knap
            .Name = "EksportKnap"
            .Object.Caption = "Eksporter til PDF"
            .Left = Plads.Left + 10
            .Top = Plads.Top
            .Width = Plads.Width - 10
            .Height = Plads.Height
            .PrintObject = False
        End With

        Kode = "Private Sub EksportKnap_Click()" & vbNewLine
        Kode = Kode & "Call Eksporter" & vbNewLine
        Kode = Kode & "End Sub"

        With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets("Indleveringsplan (2)").CodeName).CodeModule
            .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, Kode
        End With

    End Sub
```

I'm assuming that I need to add something along the lines of BackgroundColor inside the With Knap, but I can't get it to work.

That being said, I would also like to underline the text, change its font and font size as well as make it bold.

Comment: backcolor does that help?

Comment: The `OleObject` encapsulates the `CommandButton` and exposes its interface via `.Object` so `.Object.BackColor = vbRed` and `.Object.<any button property> = xxx`

Comment: Adding .BackColor = RGB(255,0,0) inside the With results in an Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @ Alex K. That works, lovely. Can you add it as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OleObject` encapsulates the `CommandButton` and exposes its interface via `.Object` so `.Object.BackColor = vbRed`.

You can use a typed variable to get intellisense:

```
Dim Button As CommandButton
With Knap
    Set Button = .Object
    With Button
        .Caption = "Eksporter til PDF"
        .BackColor = vbRed
        .Font.Underline = True
        ...
    End With
    ...
End With
```