# Make letters bold in text of button using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following VBA to insert a button into the Excel Sheet:

```
Sub Insert_Button ()
    Sheet1.Select

    Dim Button_01 As Button
    Set Button_01 = Sheet1.Buttons.Add(423.75, 0, 48, 15)

    Dim Range_Button_01 As Range
    Set Range_Button_01 = Sheet1.Range("B6:D7")
    Button_01.Name = "Button_01"

    With Button_01
        .Top = 30
        .Left = 76
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 20
        .Text = "Button_01"
    End With

End Sub
```

All this works perfectly.

---

Now, I want that `.Text = "Button_01"` appears in **bold** letters. 
What do I need to change in my code to make this work?

Comment: @RaaaCode was faster few seconds, but this similar topic can help You in further cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542282/customize-activex-button-from-vba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this helps, you just need to set `.Font.Bold = True` before closing off the `With`.

```
Sub Insert_Button()

    Sheet1.Select

    Dim Button_01 As Button
    Set Button_01 = Sheet1.Buttons.Add(423.75, 0, 48, 15)

    Dim Range_Button_01 As Range
    Set Range_Button_01 = Sheet1.Range("B6:D7")
    Button_01.Name = "Button_01"

    With Button_01
        .Top = 30
        .Left = 76
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 20
        .Text = "Button_01"
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

End Sub
```